# Reference request for a lemma on the expected value of Hermitian polynomials of Gaussian random variables.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am looking for a reference of the following lemma, specifically a textbook on which I can self-study the statement and the proof

> If $(U,V)$ a gaussian vector such that $U,V \sim N(0,1)$ then for all
>   $p,q \in N$
>
> $$E[H_q(U) H_p(V)]= q! E[UV]^q $$
>
> If $p=q$. ( $0$ if $p \ne q$). Where $H_n$ is the n-th Hermitian
>   polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is treated for instance in Chapter 11.2 of *Analysis of Boolean Functions*, by Ryan O'Donnell. *(Not the most standard reference for this fact, I assume, but a convenient one as the book can be [consulted online](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~ryanod/?page_id=2334)).*

You can find a version online here: 
http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~ryanod/?p=1694 (look at the derivation leading to (5), and providing the proof of Proposition 31).